# Exchange Powershell in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have a bunch of powershell commands within c# however one is returning 0 results and I just cant figure it out, so with the power of the internet I am hoping you guys have an answer.

My c# code running the power is as follows

```
internal static List<ExchangeMailboxes> ExchangeMailboxList(string snapIn)
        {
            List<ExchangeMailboxes> data = new List<ExchangeMailboxes>();
            StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuild.AppendLine("$script:WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'");
            stringBuild.AppendLine(
                "Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName,@{name='TotalItemSize';expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split('(')[1].Split(' ')[0].Replace(',','')/1GB),2)}},@{name='TotalDeletedItemSize';expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalDeletedItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split('(')[1].Split(' ')[0].Replace(',','')/1GB),2)}}");
            using (PowerShell inst = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                inst.AddScript("Add-PSSnapin " + snapIn)
                    .AddScript(stringBuild.ToString());
                Collection<PSObject> results = inst.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    data.Add(new ExchangeMailboxes()
                    {
                        Name = obj.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString(),
                        InboxSize = obj.Members["TotalItemSize"].Value.ToString(),
                        DeletedSize = obj.Members["TotalDeletedItemSize"].Value.ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

I can confirm that the snapin is loading correctly and if I run the powershell command manually it is all fine  and I con confirm there are no rights issues

here is the powershell command in its raw format

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName,@{name='TotalItemSize';expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split('(')[1].Split(' ')[0].Replace(',','')/1GB),2)}},@{name='TotalDeletedItemSize';expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalDeletedItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split('(')[1].Split(' ')[0].Replace(',','')/1GB),2)}}
```

Comment: What Exchange version are you targeting?

Comment: it targets multiple versions, I am running it on a exchange 2010 server and like I said I can confirm it loads the correct snap-in

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to interact with Exchange 2010 and newer is to open a session to http://servername/powershell using the microsoft.exchange configuration:

```
$ExSession = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri ‘http://ExServer1.contoso.com/PowerShell/?SerializationLevel=Full’ -Credential $Credentials –Authentication Kerberos
```

I've never tried remoting from c# code, but I guess it shouldn't be any different than what your doing now (except for the powershell code itself, of course). Since you're interacting with various "size" attributes in Exchange, it is still recommended to have the management tools installed locally, otherwise those values don't serialize/deserialize properly (you'll find other posts on serverfault on that topic).

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I actually got it running perfectly if I run it under the local system account, if I run it as an admin it wont work.